# Linux C - Get Lock Keys Status'

Tags: c, linux, keyboard

How exactly does one find out the status of the lock keys on Linux (2.6.x), using C?

(I have a *crappy* keyboard without LED's for this stuff, and I need to write an X11 app to do this)

If such an app exists (**and is DE agnostic** - I run e16), I'd also like to hear it as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the led addon to gkrellm. If you want to develop your own app, you can always look a the [gkrellm-led sources](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/maverick/gkrellm-leds) (Ubuntu). And, of course, you can always go with xkbvleds [(source)](ftp://ftp.ulakbim.gov.tr/NetBSD/NetBSD-release-5-0/xsrc/xfree/xc/programs/xkbutils/xkbvleds.c).

Anyway, you can always use [`XkbGetIndicatorState`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xkbgetindicatorstate) to read the indicators from your keyboard.